# combine regex to match subgroups in different order

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with may have one of the 2 below structure

```
(\w+){1}([!][a-zA-Z0-9>,]+)*([#]\d+)?

(\w+){1}([#]\d+)?([!][a-zA-Z0-9>,]+)*
```

some examples would be

```
"Abc1!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO!pQr5st#1400"
"Abc1#1400!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO!pQr5st"
```

The goal is to match as below

```
["Abc1", "!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO", "!pQr5st", "#1400"]
["Abc1", "#1400", "!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO", "!pQr5st"]
```

I can manage to get the result with 3 regex, but not with 1

```
const a = str.match(/\w+/)
const b = str.match(/([!][a-zA-Z0-9>,]+)/g)
const c = str.match(/[#]\d+/)
```

**How can I get the expected result with a single regex ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `|` to separate possible matches:

```js
const regExp = /\w+|![a-zA-Z0-9>,]+|#\d+/g;

console.log("Abc1!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO!pQr5st#1400".match(regExp));
console.log("Abc1#1400!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO!pQr5st".match(regExp));
```

Also note that `(\w+){1}` is equivalent to `\w+`, and `[!]` and `[#]` are the same as `!` and `#` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I did something like that, the only issue is if for some reason i get a string with some noise at end `"Abc1!deF2>Ghi3,4jlmNO!pQr5st#1400fhdhd"`which will match `\w+`. I tried playing with `(?=...)`to match any order, but without success so far, it usually matches the first occurence of the !# groups

Comment: I see. Well, if you don't want `\w+` to match at the end of the string you could prepend an `^` anchor, i.e.: `/^\w+|![a-zA-Z0-9>,]+|#\d+/g`

Comment: I guess it'd do the job ! I'm still wondering how I could have got the same result with `(?=..)`, but nvm. Thanks a lot !